# GTM триггер для отправки формы маркето

Tags: google-analytics

В страницу сайта на Wordpress вставлена форма маркето. Нужно создать триггер который отправит тэг после успешной отправки формы.
Я пытался выбрать Тип триггера 'Form Submission' и в качестве фильтра ставил 'Click Text->contains->mktoButton' и 'Form Class->contains->mktoForm'.
Как я только не пробовал, но триггер не срабатывает.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать триггер который сработает после отправки формы маркето.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос не решили, то в gtm активируем все встроенные переменные. Включаем редим отладки и отправляем форму.

Смотрим какие данные в переменных получаем при клике и отправке. По ним уже делаем тригер. Еще как костыль сделать по переменной формы - юзер ивент, ним и делать тригер.